# What is the difference between the HATEOAS and RESTful Api doc frameworks, such as Swagger2

Tags: spring, rest, hateoas

The idea behind HATEOAS is actually very simple, that is, in response to a link containing other resources that the client can use to interact with the server, the client cannot know that the server workflow, but can know the next steps in the resource link from the root links, but only the link, not Request parameters and examples This is a far cry from the online documentation generated by Swagger2 (personal feeling)
On the other hand, when it comes to code writing, looking at Spring Hateoas or using Spring ApplicationListener is hard-coded, it feels very cumbersome and feels like no swagger2 annotations are easy to use.
This problem bothers me, I don't know if my API should use the Hatepas way

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54839672/difference-between-swagger-hateoas

Comment: @CRR yes, they are the same, thank you