# HATEOAS and forms driven by the API

Tags: json-ld, spring-hateoas, hateoas, json-api, collection-json

I'm trying to apply HATEOAS to the existing application and I'm having trouble with modeling a form inputs that would be driven by the API response.

The app is allowing to search & book connections between two places. First endpoint allows for searching the connections `GET /connections?from={lat,lon}&to={lat,lon}&departure={dateTime}` and returns following payload (response body).

```json
[
  {
    "id": "aaa",
    "carrier": "Fast Bus",
    "price": 3.20,
    "departure": "2019-04-05T12:30"
  },
  {
    "id": "bbb",
    "carrier": "Airport Bus",
    "price": 4.60,
    "departure": "2019-04-05T13:30"
  },
  {
    "id": "ccc",
    "carrier": "Slow bus",
    "price": 1.60,
    "departure": "2019-04-05T11:30"
  }
]
```

In order to make an order for one of connections, the client needs to make a `POST /orders` request with one of following payloads (request body):

- email required

  ```json
  {
    "connectionId": "aaa",
    "email": "passenger@example.org"
  }
  ```
- email & flight number required (carrier handles only aiprort connections)

  ```json
  {
    "connectionId": "bbb",
    "email": "passenger@example.org",
    "flightNumber": "EA1234"
  }
  ```
- phone number required

  ```json
  {
    "connectionId": "ccc",
    "phoneNumber": "+44 111 222 333"
  }
  ```

The payload is different, because different connections may be handled by different carriers and each of them may require some different set of information to provide. I would like to inform the API client, what fields are required when creating an order. The question I have is how do I do this with HATEOAS?

I checked different specs and this is what I could tell from reading the specs:

1. [HAL](http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html) & [HAL-FORMS](https://rwcbook.github.io/hal-forms/#_example_hal_forms_document) There are `"_templates"` but, there is no URI in the template itself. It’s presumed to operate on the self link, which in my case would be **/connections...** not **/orders**.
2. [JSON-LD](https://json-ld.org/learn.html) I couldn't find anything about forms or templates support.
3. [JSON-API](https://jsonapi.org/) I couldn't find anything about forms or templates support.
4. [Collection+JSON](http://amundsen.com/media-types/collection/) There is at most one `"template"` per document, therefore it's presumed that all elements of the collection have the same fields which is not the case in my app.
5. [Siren](https://github.com/kevinswiber/siren) Looks like the `"actions"` would fit my use case, but the project seems dead and there are no supporting libraries for many major languages.
6. [CPHL](https://github.com/mikestowe/CPHL) The project seems dead, very little documentation and no libraries.
7. [Ion](https://ionspec.org/) There is nice support for forms, but I couldn't find any supporting libraries. Looks like it's just a spec for now.

Is such a common problem as having forms driven by the API still unsolved with spec and tooling?

Comment: I totally agree that especially on the support for teaching clients how requests should look like a lot of work still has to be done. I'm aware of [halo+json](http://halform.herokuapp.com/) that unfortunately is not yet [registered with IANA](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml). As explained in an [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55311547/how-to-handle-the-introduction-of-a-new-object-property-in-a-rest-api/55314514#55314514) HTML forms unfortunately only support [GET and POST](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sec-forms.html#element-attrdef-form-method)

Comment: Speaking for JSON-LD you could take a look at Hydra (http://www.hydra-cg.com) to describe supported API operations and their payloads.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, it appears that `Connections` are resources. It's not completely clear if `Orders` are truly resources. I'm guessing probably yes, but to have an `Order` you need a `Client` and `Connection`. So, to create an `Order` you will need to expose a collection, likely from the `Client` or `Connection`, possibly both.

I think the disconnect is from thinking along the lines of "now that we've got a list of available connections, the client can select one and create an `Order`." That's perfectly valid, but it's remote procedure call (RPC) thinking, not REST. Neither is objectively better than the other, except in the context of a particular set of project requirements, and generally they shouldn't be mixed together.

With an RPC mindset, a create order method is defined (e.g. using OpenAPI) and any clients are expected to use some out-of-band information to determine the correct form required (i.e. by reading the OpenAPI spec).

With a REST/HATEOAS mindset, the correct approach would be to expose a `Orders` collection from `Connection`. Each `Connection` in the collection has a `self` link and a `Order`s collection (link or object, as defined by app requirements). Each item of `Order` has a `self` link, and that is where the affordances are specified. An `Order` is a known type (even with REST/HATEOAS the client and service have to at least agree on a shared vocabulary) that the client presumably knows how to define. That vocabulary can be defined using any mechanism that works -- json-ld, XSD, etc.

HATEOAS requires that the result contains everything the client needs to update the state. There can be no out-of-band information (other than the shared vocabulary). So, to solve your issue, you either need to expose a collection of `Order`s from `Connection` or you need to allow an `Order` to be created by posting to `Connection`. If the latter seems like a bit of a hack, it probably is.

For example, in HAL-Forms, I would do something like:

```
{
  "connections": [{
    "id": "aaa",
    "carrier": "Fast Bus",
    "price": 3.20,
    "departure": "2019-04-05T12:30"
    "_links": { 
      "self": { ... }, // link to this connection
      "orders": {} // link to collection of orders for this connection
    }
  },
  , ...],
  "_links": {
    "self": { ... } // link to the collection
  },
  "_templates": { ... } // post/put/patch/delete connection
}
```

Clients would follow the links to `orders` and from there would get the `_templates` collection that contains the instructions for managing the `Order` resources. The `Order` POST would likely require a connection identifier and client information. The [HAL-Forms Spec](https://rwcbook.github.io/hal-forms/) defines a regex property that can be used to specify the type of data to supply for any particular form element. Since you have reached the order by navigating through a specific connection, you would be able to specify in your `_templates` for that order exactly which fields are required. e.g. `/orders?connectionType=aaa` would return a different set of required properties than `/orders?connectionType=bbb` but both use the same `self` link of `/orders?connectionType={type}` and you'd validate it on POST/PUT/PATCH.

I should note that the Spring-HATEOAS goes beyond the HAL-Forms spec and allows for multiple `_links` and `_templates`. See [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/mamund/hal-forms/issues/24).

It may look like HATEOAS/REST requires quite a bit more work than a simple OpenAPI/RPC API and it does. But what you are giving up in simplicity, you are gaining in flexibility and resilience, assuming well-designed clients. Which approach is correct depends on a lot of factors, most of them not technical (team skills, expected consumers, how much control you have over clients, maintenance, etc.).

Comment: A template can have a target property, which overrides the default self link, so you can safely add multiple submit order templates to the resource, and have them fulfilled by different controllers, each with their own validation.