# How to validate headers using producerApiDoc property of restConfiguration in Camel REST DSL

Tags: java, rest, apache-camel, swagger, request-validation

I am setting up a validation framework for REST endpoint using Camel REST DSL. I came across RestConfiguration property "producerApiDoc". I have a swagger/openAPI YAML file and trying to pass it as the argument for doing the request validation but the validation doesn't happen. Below is the code for making this configuration.

Here's the Camel REST DSL documentation [link](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/rest-dsl.html)!

```java
public class EmployeeRouterConfig extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

    // Rest and Swagger configuration
    restConfiguration().bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json).producerApiDoc("C:\\project\\workspace\\employee-management\\schema\\Employee-system-services-api-35.yaml")
    .component("servlet")
    .dataFormatProperty("prettyPrint", "true")
    .dataFormatProperty("json.in.enableFeatures",
            "FAIL_ON_NUMBERS_FOR_ENUMS,USE_BIG_DECIMAL_FOR_FLOATS" +
            ",FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES,ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE")
    .dataFormatProperty("json.in.disableFeatures", "FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS")
    .enableCORS(true).port(env.getProperty("server.port", "8080"))
    .contextPath(contextPath.substring(0, contextPath.length() -
            2)).apiContextPath("/api-doc") .apiProperty("api.title","Employee Management").apiProperty("api.version", "1.0.0").clientRequestValidation(true);
```

I'm expecting a validation to take place based on the yaml file specified and to thrown Bad request exception, but actually the validation is not happening and the flow continues with success OK message

Comment: The [official documentation](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/rest-dsl.html#_client_request_validation) lists what it actually validates, unfortunately Swagger/OpenAPI YML files are not included here yet. Further, Swagger, OpenAPI or Camel's so called Rest-DSL have actually [hardly anything to do with REST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54839672/difference-between-swagger-hateoas/54841309#54841309) itself other than to misuse the term for HTTP related exchange of messages (via RPC style APIs and consumers)

Comment: As per the REST DSL documentation, We can do validation using yaml file. I tried specifying producerAPISpec to file:c:/project/workspace/employee-management/schema/employee-system-services-api-35.yaml" and added dependecy `testCompile group: 'org.apache.camel', name: 'camel-swagger-java', version: '2.24.2'` in build.gradle, still the validation is not happening.