# Rest API Hateoas : Should API response have identifiers as hard coded or as placeholders?

Tags: rest, api, api-design, hateoas

[Link to the HATEOAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS) This is the link to the Hateoas article (snapshot below) where the identifiers of the resource is part of the URL i.e. 12345. Here the API response has the final API relative URL i.e. /accounts/12345/deposit and the client just needs to hit it.

[image: Hateoas wikipedia picture]

[Link to the Github Users API](https://developer.github.com/v3/users/) This is the link to the Github API (snapshot below) where there are lots of placeholders for identifiers. How will clients modify these URLSs and add a value in these placeholders? For example, {/gist_id}, {/other_user}.

Isn't passing the URL with id value instead of placeholder better? Why and when to rely on different clients to add values in these placeholders?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hypertext as the engine of application state (HATEOAS) is a bit more than just the usage of links. In essence it enforces the interaction model that is used on the Web for two decades quite successfully. On the web a server usually "teaches" clients (browsers) to achieve something via the help of [link relations](https://www.iana.org/assignments/link-relations/link-relations.xhtml), that can be used to automatically download related resources or give a hint on the reference resource, and [Web forms](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html), that define the syntax and semantics of each of the respective supported (input) elements, i.e. a text field, an option element to select one or multiple choices, a drop down or even a slider widget. Based on the [affordance](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QIv9YR1bMwY&t=817) of each of the elements a client knows i.e. that a button wants to be clicked or pressed while a text fields wants some user input and stuff or a link annotated with the `prefetch` link relation name may be downloaded automatically once the current page finished loading as a client might invoke it next or a `preload` link relation might instruct a user agent to load the referenced resource early in the current page loading process.

The form not only teaches a client about the supported fields a resource has but also about the target URI to send the request to, the HTTP method to use wile sending the request as well as the media-type, which in the case of Web forms is usually implicitly set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

In an ideal world a client just uses the information given by the server. Unfortunately, the world isn't perfect and over time people have come up with plenty of other solutions. Among one of them is [URI templating](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570) that basically allows clients to use a basic URI and fill out certain placeholders with concrete values. As making use of templating requires some knowledge of the URIs intention or the parameters you need to pass, such capabilities make only sense as part of media-type support.

Plain JSON (`application/json`) has by default no support for URIs whatsoever and as such a user agent receiving a plain JSON payload might not be able to automatically replace a template URI with a concrete one out of the box. [JSON Hyper-Schema](http://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/json-schema-hypermedia.html) (`application/schema+json`) attempts to add link and URI template support to plain JSON payloads. A user client though needs to be hinted with the appropriate media-type in order to automatically resolve the full URI. As such, the user agent also has to support that respective media type otherwise it won't be able to process the document (resolve the template URI to a real URI) successfully.

JSON Hypertext Application Language a.k.a [HAL JSON](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-kelly-json-hal-08#section-5.2) also supports URI templates for links. [`application/collection+json`](http://amundsen.com/media-types/collection/format/#objects-template) does support two kinds of templates - [query templates](http://amundsen.com/media-types/collection/format/#query-templates) and [objects-template](http://amundsen.com/media-types/collection/format/#objects-template). The primer one is similar to a URI template by allowing to append certain query parameters to the target URI upon sending the request while the latter one allows to define a whole object that contains all the input elements used to add or edit an item within the collection. [JSON-LD](https://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld/) does not really support URI templating AFAIK though it uses the concept of a so called context where certain terms can be used to abbreviate URIs. As such something like `name` can be used within the context for a URI like `http://schema.org/name`.

As you can hopefully see, the support for URI templating depends on the media-type used for exchanging data. In the case of the outlined github example `GET /users/:username` this more or less resembles a typical Web API documentation, similar as it is done in a [Swagger API documentation](https://swagger.io/tools/swagger-ui/), that unfortunately [has hardly anything to do with HATEOAS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54839672/difference-between-swagger-hateoas).

Answer (score 0):

For your top example (banking), you should absolutely include the complete URL, with account numbers (IDs), so that the client does not need to translate/substitute anything.  This is the most common scenario with HATEOAS.  However, GitHub does have those "placeholders" for endpoints that could contain multiple values. You can't include the "following_url" for every user in the response, it's not practical.  So you have to determine the "other_user" value another way and make the substitution.  Personally, I haven't even had this use case with any  of my applications and all of my HATEOAS URLs resemble you first example (though I prefer full URLs not relative).  Unless you have specific cases like GitHub does, it's not necessary to use any of these placeholders.  Even GitHub only uses that where they could be multiple values.  For fixed value URLs, they have the username (like your account number) in the URL ("octocat").

Answer (score 0):

According to me we should not give the direct url in the body
We should always parameterized the api and get details form there.
In simple case if Id of data change than every time data need to update for detail url.
Else if it’s dynamic you will never face this issue.
And this also come under best practices.

Comment: Yeah I think it's a proper approach as there is no point of single truth in our database and since database might keep on changing this approach seems good.