# RestAPI. Is it ok to demand optional parameters depending on client configuration?

Tags: rest

We are designing a RESTful API.

Sample request:

```
{
    "transaction_id" : abc,
    "sale_value" : 100,
    "profit_value" : 2
}
```

**profit_value** is an optional field. However, based on client configuration, the field is either mandatory or it is ignored even if supplied by the client (in this case we calculate it ourselves and return it in the response).

Is that good practice?

i.e. Is it ok to demand a field even when the API specification defines it as optional?

And is it ok to ignore a field, that even though it is optional, was supplied?

Answer (score 0):

In a REST architecture the server should teach a client on how certain things can be achieved. This is very similar to the browseable Web where a HTML form page teaches a user not only on the available data elements that can be filled by the client, but also teaches a client on the HTTP operation to use, the HTTP endpoint to send the request to as well as the media type format the response has to be sent in.

> profit_value is an optional field. However, based on client configuration, the field is either mandatory or it is ignored even if supplied by the client (in this case we calculate it ourselves and return it in the response).
>
> Is that good practice?

If you are teaching a client to send the request via `POST` the request is basically processed [according the resource's own specific semantics](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.3). This means that you are of course allowed to ignore or change certain user input to your liking or even decline a request that contains or misses certain input data.

From the given problem statement it is unclear whether the client itself is configuring the mandatory or optional fields or whether it is given by the service provider themselves. Therefore it is unclear how a client knows whether a certain input is mandatory or optional (and thus may be ignored as a consequence). In case a certain field will be ignored by the server, the best option here would be to not even teach that client about that field at all and as such don't include control elements within the form'esque representation format sent as a response from the server to the client. A mandatory element will for sure be evaluated on the server side and in case of constraint validations (missing or not in the correct range or the like) the server will reject the request with a *400 Bad Request*  response that indicates that a certain expected input parameter is missing. This is how HTTP and HTML operate for decades and this is basically how REST should behave as well.

By *API specification* I guess you mean something like Swagger or the like?! Unfortunately [such API documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54839672/difference-between-swagger-hateoas/54841309#54841309) has hardly anything to do with REST as it is pretty similar to traditional interface definition languages (IDL) of common RPC solutions (CORBA, WSDL for SOAP, stub-classes for RMI, ...). In such a case, however, the server can't really support a client on whether a field is mandatory, optional or may even be ignored at all. You might introduce a further resource a client can query to learn whether it supports a certain field or parameter and in such a case add it to the request. This, however, needs to be documented very clearly to avoid confusion on the client side.