# REST API design: what is a unique operation or resource

Tags: rest, swagger, jax-rs, openapi

Years ago I created [a tiny web service](https://github.com/marcelstoer/open-data-smn/) that serves the same resource in two representations.

```
# returns a collection of Foos
GET /foo
# returns the same collection of Foos in a different JSON representation
GET /foo?projection=X with 'Accept: my-specific-media-type'
```

This works quite well in (Java) code as I can have two methods mapped to the same `@Path` both with different return types. One accepts a `@QueryParam` and `@Consumes` a specific media type while the other doesn't.

However, according to the (current) [`@ApiOperation`](https://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/v1.5.0/apidocs/io/swagger/annotations/ApiOperation.html) Swagger annotation I opted for the wrong API design.

> A combination of a HTTP method and a path creates a unique operation

Hence, after I upgraded my old project to current library versions the Swagger model only contains a single `GET /foo` operation - which one is random as it depends on runtime code introspection through Java reflections.

So, the question is this: is the `Foo` resource *in a different representation* effectively the "same" resource or is it a different resource? The Swagger annotation seems to hint at the latter (different resource -> different path).

Comment: Usually content type negotiation (i.e. using `Accept` and `Content-Type` headers) is used for letting both server and client determine which representation format to use. In case of HTML forms, i.e., the media type to send to the server is either implicitly (`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`) or explicitly given. Unfortunately, [Swagger has hardly anything to do with REST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54839672/difference-between-swagger-hateoas/54841309#54841309)

Comment: Yep, I'm fully aware of the content type negotiation considerations. Regardless of _how_ the client expresses which representation it wants to use there's the questions of whether a representation of `Foo` makes a resource. Is `Foo` the resource or is `Foo`-as-JSON the resource? Swagger has a lot to do with REST as Swagger became the OpenAPI 2 spec which in turn lead to OpenAPI 3. The Q you linked to talks about Swagger vs. _HATEOAS_. In neither OpenAPI 2 nor 3 you can specify a path with multiple differing response types.

Comment: Resources in a REST architecture are [untyped](http://soabits.blogspot.com/2012/04/restful-resources-are-not-typed.html). In general the data, regardless of its representation, is what defines a resource. The representation is just the concrete instance of that date with respect to the chosen media-type. And again, Swagger has not much to do with REST at all. If so, it enforces a false picture of what is and is actually closer to RPC than to REST. Sure, for those "pseudo-REST" APIs which spread the wrong meaing, you might get the impression that it does belong to the REST stack, which it dosnt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part of the problem that you are running into is a mix of REST concepts and Swagger/OpenAPI concepts.

[Resource](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_2_1_1) is a REST concept: "any concept that might be the target of an author's hypertext reference must fit within the definition of a resource"

[Representation](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_2_1_2) is a REST concept: "A representation is a sequence of bytes, plus representation metadata to describe those bytes."

[Operations](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/paths-and-operations/) are an OpenAPI concept: "OpenAPI defines a unique operation as a combination of a path and an HTTP method."

There's a certain amount of tension here because the viewpoints aren't actually in alignment with each other.

For example, from the perspective of REST, there's no reason to document a "GET operation", because GET is part of the uniform interface - it has the same semantics no matter what value is used as the target-uri.  That's a part of a key architectural constraint that makes the world wide web possible - consistent semantics means that we can use general purpose components (like *web browsers*) to interact with *all* of the different resources on the web.

---

> is the Foo resource in a different representation effectively the "same" resource or is it a different resource?

"It depends".

A classic example of "one resource, different representations" would be a picture, where we might have a GIF, JPEG, PNG, BMP.  Same picture (ish), but different sequences of bytes that need to be processed in different ways.

Similarly, you might have a web page (HTML), and also a text/plain representation, or a JSON representation, etc.

One of the important questions to ask: is a general purpose cache going to have the information necessary to return the "correct" representation for a request?

That said: given that your original design was using a query parameter to distinguish one projection from another, you should likely respect that instinct and continue to treat the different representations as belonging to different resources (meaning that general purpose caches will keep them completely separate).

Whether that means that you want to share the same path /foo (treating *projection* as an optional @ApiParam), or give each projection a different path (defining separate operations for each unique path) is less clear.  In a brownfield project, my bias would be toward documenting what you already have, rather than making a bunch of breaking changes.

But it is certainly reasonable to treat "easy to document" as a design constraint.

Comment: Thanks for this thoughtful answer balancing REST and OpenAPI! I didn't work on that tiny project for a few years and just realized that I actually _am_ using content negotiation through `Accept` header. Consequently I also added `Accept` to the `Vary` header to play nice with caches. The `projection` parameter is still important but not essential. I updated the Q accordingly. However, the picture doesn't change all that much. Sometime in the last couple of years the Swagger/OpenAPI community decided to treat my two operations is one and no longer two.

Answer (score 1):

> So, the question is this: is the Foo resource in a different representation effectively the "same" resource or is it a different resource?

Fielding defined a resource as such:

> The key abstraction of information in REST is a resource. **Any information that can be named can be a resource**: a document or image, a temporal service (e.g. "today's weather in Los Angeles"), a collection of other resources, a non-virtual object (e.g. a person), and so on. In other words, any concept that might be the target of an author's hypertext reference must fit within the definition of a resource. A resource is a conceptual mapping to a set of entities, not the entity that corresponds to the mapping at any particular point in time.
>
> More precisely, a resource R is a **temporally varying membership function MR(t), which for time t maps to a set of entities, or values, which are equivalent**. The values in the set may be resource representations and/or resource identifiers. A resource can map to the empty set, which allows references to be made to a concept before any realization of that concept exists -- a notion that was foreign to most hypertext systems prior to the Web [61]. *Some resources are static* in the sense that, when examined at any time after their creation, they always correspond to the same value set. *Others have a high degree of variance in their value over time*. **The only thing that is required to be static for a resource is the semantics of the mapping**, since the semantics is what distinguishes one resource from another.
>
> ...
>
> REST uses a **resource identifier to identify the particular resource involved in an interaction between components**. REST connectors provide a generic interface for accessing and manipulating the value set of a resource, regardless of how the membership function is defined or the type of software that is handling the request. The naming authority that assigned the resource identifier, making it possible to reference the resource, is responsible for maintaining the semantic validity of the mapping over time (i.e., ensuring that the membership function does not change). ([Source](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm))

In short, a resource is something that you give a name in order to reference it later on. This resource is a container for data. That data can be represented in plenty of ways. A representation is a concrete instance of the resource' data with respect to the media-type the representation was created for. The media-type itself defines the syntax and semantic of a concrete instance. I.e. [HTML](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html) defines which attributes and elements are admissible within the payload and what these things express.

As REST [shouldn't have typed "resources" meaningful to clients](http://soabits.blogspot.com/2012/04/restful-resources-are-not-typed.html) content type negotiation should be used. Here a client express its capabilities via the `Accept` header to the server and the server will chose a representation format that will suite the data the best. A well-behaved server will only chose among the suggested media types as it knows the client can handle the data. A non-well-behaved client will just ignore the header and send whatever it wants which eventually may prevent clients from being able to process the payload at all.

REST is all about decoupling of clients from servers and allowing the server side from evolving in future without breaking clients. This however is only possible if both use some kind of indirection. I.e. not the URI itself is the relevant thing in a payload but the link-relations that are attached to that URI. A link relation might be something like `next`, `prev`, `first` or `last` for a traversable collection or something like `prefetch` witch just states that the content of the annotated URI may be loaded once the client has loaded all other things and is currently IDLE as this content may be requested next with some likelihood. Such link relations are either [standardized](https://www.iana.org/assignments/link-relations/link-relations.xhtml) or should follow the extension mechanism defined in [Web Linking](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8288#section-2.1.2).

In regards to your actual question. Think of an arbitrary product `ABC1234`. This product contains some properties such as its price, the current number of items in stock, some metadata describing the product and what not. These properties might be expressed in JSON, in XML or in HTML. Clients which are able to process these media-types will be able to create an "object" with the same properties with hardly any issues. The actual representation format used shouldn't have an influence on the actual data of the resource itself. After all, the representation format is just a mutually agreed way of exchanging the data between client and server in order to allow the recipient of the payload to process it in the same way the sender intended it initially.

As Fielding mentioned before, such a resource may be static or change over time. With the product example from above, the price may change over time, though this doesn't change the semantics of the actual product. Over time sometimes the same data that is present for a resource need to be made available as part of an other resource. This is totally fine and here things start to get a bit more interesting. As part of a company merger one of our clients needed to expose all of their items with different names. In their case they opted for providing both product names for a year simultaneously. By definition these would be two different resources to an arbitrary HTTP client, i.e `ABC1234` and `XYZ12345` even though they "represent" the data of the same real-live product. They could also have opted for using (permanent) redirection of clients to the "new" URI and therefore hint clients that the product is actually the same.

The resource per name (or URI) concept is also noticable if you take a look at how caching works in the HTTP ecosystem. Here the [effective request URI](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-5.5) is used as cache-key in order to look up whether for the requested URI already a stored response is present. Any unsafe operation performed on that URI will lead to an eviction of that stored response. This is i.e. one of the reasons why HTTP isn't meant for batch-operations as these may bypass the cache at all and lead to wrong and/or misleading results.

> Years ago I created a tiny web service that serves the same resource in two representations.
>
> ```
> GET /foo               # returns a collection of Foos
> GET /foo?projection=X  # returns a collection of Foos in a different coordinate system i.e.  different representation
> ```

According to how HTTP defines effective request URIs these two URIs would target two different resources actually, event though they express the same data just with different representations. A probably better approach would have been to expose just `/foo` and use either specialized media-types for the different coordinate systems or even better a media-type that supports [profiles](https://www.mnot.net/blog/2012/04/17/profiles) and hint the recipients processor via the profile attribute which "kind of" data it receives. Link relations, as mentioned above, also define a `profile` relation name that can be used to allow a client to chose between the URI returning "metric" or "imperial", "Kelvin", "Fahrenheit" or "Celsius" or similar measurement figures or the like.

So, long story short, loosely speeking the absolut URI, including matrix, query and path parameters, is what "names" a resource at an arbitrary client. The whole URI is the identifier of that resource after all. Slightly different names might result in local or intermediary cache misses and therefore indicate a different resource, even though the data expressed is the same as before. Instead of using two slighly different URIs redirection directives, content type negotiation or profiles on the same resource can be used to "get rid" of the sibling "resource" that only differ in different representation formats returned.